# Не центрируется wrapper?

Tags: веб-программирование, html, дизайн, css

страница практически чистая, на ней всего 1 элемент можно сказать это **div** с классом **.wrapper**, вся феерия в том чтобы отцентрировать его как это делается обычно при margin: 0 auto; , увы, не пойму почему этого не происходит (в посл. версии **FF** по крайней мере это так):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type"content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<style>
.wrapper { margin: 0 auto; background-color: #FF9; }
</style>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё происходит, если что... Ваш код выведет div с шириной 100%, задайте ему ширину, скажем 200px и вы увидите, как он прекрасно оцентрируется

Comment: ага, если выставляю и width и height в фиксированных пикселях, тогда появляется блок там где надо, а как быть с процентами? ставлю width: 90%; height: 90% и ничего...

Comment: Если у вас нет каких-то других параметров, которые могут влиять на этот div или документ в целом, то даже при width: 90%, блок оцентрируется нормально. И даже в последней версии FF

Comment: да он-то центрируется, но я не вижу фона, вот в чем у меня стык был, да, все правильно, в принципе, но если сайт резиновый и выглядит это все так: <div class="wrapper"><div style="height: 80%"></div></div>, то шлагбаум, нельзя px ставить мне, как ни крути, странно все это.

Comment: Ох,ох,ох... В общем, так: 
html,body { height: 100%;}
.wrapper { margin: 0 auto; background-color: #FF9; width: 90%; height: 90%; }

Comment: Ну наконец-то "Свершилось Чудо!".